# How to accept both modifiable and non-modifiable arguments?

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

I have a debugging macro where I give it a float reference, and expect it to modify that variable sometimes, if it can.

```
#define probe(x) implProbe(#x##GETLINE, (x))

void implProbe(const char * loc, float & x){
    // this signature is a place holder
    ...
    x = 4.f;
}
```

However, I would also like to use the same macro for temporary variables or literals such as `probe(1 + 2)` or `probe(x + y)`.  The macro wouldn't need to have the same effect in those cases, I don't expect to see an output from it, I only want it to not break.

```
float var = 0.f;
probe(var);
// var == 4.f

var = 0.f;
probe(var + 2.f);  // this should be legal
// var == 0.f (didn't change)

probe(1.f); // this should be legal
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: What about overloading impmProbe with float&&?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement two overloaded functions.

```
void implProbe(const char * loc, float & x){
    ...
    x = 4.f;
}
void implProbe(const char * loc, const float & x){
    ...
}
```